# CSS arrow point to currently selected li element

Tags: html, css

**Here's my jsfiddle example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/7PqqT/

Update: This is my work around solution: http://jsfiddle.net/7PqqT/1/ 

**However** I would like to achieve this same effect without needing the arrow divs to be in each li element.

Now what I'm going to be doing is having jquery addClass('current') to whichever of the 3 li elements the user clicks on, and it I want the arrow to appear below that li element in the center of the text. I'm not sure the best way to do this, I'm hoping there's a simple method to go about doing this.

Comment: Did you forget to upload your photo?

Comment: Oops, I had intended to show a photo but instead I made a jsfiddle. I've removed that, thanks haha

Comment: This would probably have to be done with javascript.  Where you looking for a css only solution?

Comment: Well, I have got one working how I want it to now, but it's not the way I would like to ultimately like to use it. The way I currently have it I have to put the arrow divs in each li element and only have them show when current is assigned to the li element, I would like to achieve the same result with just one set of arrow divs, and just change their location to the current li element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, [I updated your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7PqqT/2/).

Basically, I just deleted the arrow `div` completely and change the arrow-related CSS to `:before` and `:after` pseudoelements. Works like a charm.

Comment: Ah that's fantastic, I never knew you could do this sort of stuff with CSS